# Can anything be said about existence of limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose that a function $f(x)$ is defined for all real numbers of $x$ except $x=x_0$. Can anything be said about the existence of $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$.

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The fact that the values are defined says nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even continuity (or, more restrictively, differentiability) over $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_0\}$ is insufficient to make any general claim about the situation; compare the following examples:

\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=\sin\frac{1}{x}
\\[6px]
f_2(x)&=\frac{\sin x}{x}
\\[6px]
f_3(x)&=\frac{1}{x^2}
\end{align}

The three function are differentiable over $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$; $f_1$ has no limit at $0$, $f_2$ has limit $1$ at $0$, $f_3$ has limit $\infty$ at $0$.

It follows that you can say nothing general about this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $f$ is defined or not at $x=x_0$ is irrelevant, as the computation of the limit doesn't use $f(x_0)$ at all. (The limit precisely tries to guess the "expected" value of $f(x_0)$.)

So your question boils down to "Suppose that a function $f(x)$ is defined for all real numbers. Can anything be said about the existence of $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$."

Comment: It is not my own question but my teacher's. $x_0$ in there is just a number for example let $x_0$ be 4 and limit of the function is not defined at that point but in all other points.

Comment: @PercieJackson: your last sentence is a completely different question. Fix that.